# How to show $\int_{C}\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}=0$ for the given conditions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

$\vec{F}=(9y-y^3)\vec{i}+e^{\sqrt{y}}(x^2-3x)\vec{j}$ and $C$ is the square given by the points $(0,0)$, $(0,3)$, $(3,0)$, and $(3,3)$, oriented counterclockwise.

I have found out that $\vec{F}$ is not conservative, so we cannot just assert that it is $0$. Furthermore the book suggests showing $\vec{F}$ is orthogonal to the edges along the square, but I do not know how to do that. Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The edge between $(0,0)$ and $(0,3)$ has $x=0$ and $0\le y\le 3$, and can be parametrized as $t\vec j$, $0\le t\le 3$. What is $\vec F$ along this line segment? You should be able to work out the other edges similarly by yourself.

Comment: $\vec{F_{d\vec{x}}}=(9t-t^3)\vec{i}$, so $\vec{F_{d\vec{x}}}\cdot t\vec{j}=0$. Got it, thanks!